# Trying to position view inside ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

I try positioning my three imagebuttons in Android-studio. However, every time I use design-editor to position the imagebuttons on the correct location, it won't take affect when I run the app. Using the design-editor and not the text editor, gives this message:

> This view is not constrained, it only has designtime positions, so it will jump to (0,0) unless you add constraints less...

How do I add constraints in the xml-editor if that is all I have to do

Also, this line is added to the xml editor: 
    `tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="80dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="52dp" />`

I am using ConstraintLayout instead of RelativeLayout... 
My main.activity xml code:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/positive_Button"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:background="@null"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/positive"
    android:gravity="left"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="80dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="39dp" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/neutral_Button"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/neutral"
    android:background="@null"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="80dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="230dp" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/negative_Button"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/negative"
    android:background="@null"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="80dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="412dp" />
```

Comment: what is the parent view in your layout file????

Comment: Post your xml code.

Comment: Please provide your all XML code.

Comment: Is `ConstraintLayout` the parent layout?

Comment: Yes, ConstraintLayout is my parent layout

Comment: @Jens try to edit your question title to **Trying to position view inside `ConstraintLayout`**. So that other people facing problem can find the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Editor's design tab, right click on your Widget that is ConstraintLayout and then click Infer Constraints in the drop down list. The IDE will automatically add code for your.

```
Constraint Layout ---> Infer Constraint
```

Answer (score 1):

The attribute tools: is only used for development purposes. tools: attributes are stripped when building. How would you like to position the views? Then I can propose a solution. You could use

> android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"

To position the X for example.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

in `MainActivity.java` change the `Activity` into `AppCompactActivity`